# What does 'times=X' in Web2py LOAD-helper?

Tags: web2py

In the Web2Py book I found [this](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12/components-and-plugins#LOAD-signature): 
It states that:

> `times` specifies how many times the component is to be requested. Use "infinity" to keep loading the component continuously. This option is useful for triggering regular routines for a given document request.

How and when could this be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use it together with `timeout` to show tweets about something, or last updates, or last messages... Something that is update continuously.

This will call and show `last_messages` each 5 seconds.

```
LOAD(c='default', f='last_messages', 
     extension='load', target='mydiv',
     ajax=True, timeout=5000, times='infinity')
```